# Urllib request throws a decode error when parsing from url

Tags: python, json, decode, urllib

I'm trying to parse the json formatted data from this url: http://ws-old.parlament.ch/sessions?format=json. My browser copes nicely with the json data. But requests always throw the following error:

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 3 column 1 (char 4)

I'm using Python 3.5. And this is my code:

```
import json
import urllib.request

connection = urllib.request.urlopen('http://ws-old.parlament.ch/affairs/20080062?format=json')

js = connection.read()

info = json.loads(js.decode("utf-8"))
print(info)
```

Comment: The error is not thrown by `urllib`. It is thrown by the `json.loads()` line, apparently you didn't receive *valid* JSON data.

Comment: I get a HTML response from that URL when loading with Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site uses User-Agent filtering to only serve JS to known browsers. Luckily it is easily fooled, just set the `User-Agent` header to `Mozilla`:

```
request = urllib.request.Request(
    'http://ws-old.parlament.ch/affairs/20080062?format=json',
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla'})

connection = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
js = connection.read()

info = json.loads(js.decode("utf-8"))
print(info)
```

Comment: Thanks so much Martjin, this just works beautifully.